# Move option to primary context menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, context-menu

Is it possible to see the option Open with Code inside the primary context menu (left one) instead of in Show more options?

[image]

I don't want to switch back to the old Windows 10 context menu, but I use this option frequently.

Comment: I don't want to see all options, I just want this one specifically.

Comment: You can either revert back to the old context menu or get used to the new context menu. I am not aware of any efforts or projects that will allow you to customize the new context menu the way you want

Comment: Annoying that the new Edit in Notepad has appeared on the main menu; but we cant make our preferred commands to be added

Comment: Shift-Right click is only a workaround. Hoping for something to be improved on this front. I like the new menu but not being customisable is a big fail